# .env.local file can not be ignored in .gitignore in Symfony 5.3

Tags: git, gitignore

I would like to ignore a file named `.env.local` file so it's not committed, because I have some local parameters in it and my team workers have their own local parameters in it. So we want only `.env` to be commited.

But the .env.local file can not be ignored by my .gitignore file :

```
/.env.local.php
/.env.local
/.env.*.local
```

while any other files in .gitignore file is correctly ignored.

Comment: Well that seems quite mysterious.  Are you positive you are looking at the correct .gitignore file?

Comment: If the file is already tracked, listing it in `.gitignore` will have no effect. Is the file already tracked? (The output of `git ls-files --stage .env.local` will tell you.)

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-can-i-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitign

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @joanis @torek,

As you showed, this command fixed my probleme :

`git rm --cached .env.local`